# Validation not working on client side in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I am rendering a partial view but my asp validation does not work on client side. It does work on server side as it does not in fact update invalid values.

My model is derived from a base class but I don't see why that could cause any errors

My model:

```
public class HSAccount : GameAccount
{
    [Display(Name = "Highest Rank")]
    [Range(1, 25)]
    public int HSRank { get; set; }

    public HSAccount()
    {
        Game = "Hearthstone";
        Genre = GameGenre.CCG;
        HSRank = 1;
    }
}
```

The display name annotation **does work** but the user can type in any integer without getting an error warning.

```
<div class="form-group game-form">
        <label asp-for="HSRank" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="HSRank" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="HSRank" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

This is a preview where as stated no validation error is detected:

[image]

If there is any doubt this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Edit: This is how I'm rendering my view:

```
 @Html.Partial("/Views/Game/_EditHS.cshtml", (ProjectMentor.Models.Games.HSAccount)ViewBag.HSAccount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use htmlHelpers in your cshtml file and bind your properties with the input. It will automatically add all html5 validation to the input

For example

m.FirstName) %>
                m.FirstName) %>

Comment: Hi can you elaborate how to use them in my case? I thought asp-for already did that.